# Can Google and Cloudflare find my SE password?

Tags: discussion, support, login, privacy

We are using Firefox with the [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) extension on GNU/Linux, mainly for security reasons.

When we go to the login page of a Stack Exchange site, say https://mathoverflow.net, the NoScript extension blocks JavaScript from Google and Cloudflare and examining the HTML source, shows SCRIPT from Google.

Users who browse with JavaScript globally enabled will have the JavaScript silently executed.

We strongly believe JavaScript in an HTML page has full access to the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and can find the password when entered/autocompleted.

This might be an issue, especially if the password is reused.

- Is it true that Google and/or Cloudflare can find my SE password if I allow JavaScript?
- What part of the small print of the SE EULA addresses
  third parties accessing my password?

It was crossposted from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/tour), and now it is only here.

Comment: @RobertLongson well, it's a general question about SE, so better fit here.

Comment: It sounds like a question for *[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour)*. I would imagine the general case is already covered in an existing question. Some leads: *[Potential attack vectors using JavaScript to log in](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85569/potential-attack-vectors-using-javascript-to-log-in)*, *[Is there malicious HTML?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/251422/is-there-malicous-html/)*, and *[Why is the same origin policy so important?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/)*.

Comment: Asked at insecurity.SE https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/265707/does-the-se-login-page-need-hardening-against-third-party-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be very hand-wavy.

If you use a Stack Exchange login, then the only POST would be going to Stack Exchange and no extra data would be sent to other sites.  Since the DOM is not dynamic, and the event that controls sending the password lives on the stackexchange.com domain, Google and Cloudflare would likely not have access to the timing of when that event fires off, and wouldn't be able to intercept your password.

(There's also this whole SSL thing that stands in the way too...)

Personally I wouldn't fret about it too much.

Comment: I still didn't check for sure, but I believe third party JS that is included in a page does have access to the DOM, so a simple `document.getElementById('password').value` will give the raw password. It can be read with a timer every second, and when not empty, sent anywhere along with other details identifying the user.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yes, if the JavaScript is running in the same page as the input element containing the password, then, yes, that JavaScript does have access to the raw password and could send it anywhere it wanted to. The only way to prevent this and still have third-party code in the main frame would be to have the password input in a sandboxed `<iframe>` which has only first-party JavaScript loaded into it. Note: your suggestion to read the input via a timer is poor, as there are various events which could/should be used instead to get called when the input text changes.

Comment: I disagree with your answer. You are assuming good faith, and I don't assume it. The basic idea @ShadowTheKidWizard is simple PoC, but I agree for an attack it must be modified, which is doable.

Comment: @Makyen From long and bitter experience with events in various languages, timer is the only thing that always "work" no matter what. Events sometimes simply don't trigger, for reasons we'll never know. Might be poor, might be non elegant, but it just *works*. :)

Comment: -1.  "Wouldn't fret", my banking site does this.